# set default datatype = char (instead of varchar)

Tags: sql-server

I'm setting up a database in SQL-2014 that is exchanging data with a mainframe. All the fields are char, so there are trailing spaces. In table designer, my default field type is varchar.

Is there a way to change this one database so the default field type will be char as I create new tables?

Comment: The default column data type in the SSMS table designer is not configurable.  Is that the table designer are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

The default column data type in the SQL Server Management Studio table designer is not currently configurable.  If this feature is important to you, consider submitting a suggestion on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback).  Be sure to specify why the feature has value to you and your organization (e.g. enhanced productivity).

The default type is configurable in the Visual Studio IDE, though.  In VS 2015, the option is available under Options-->Database Tools-->Table and Database Designers-->Column Options.